# Sweet alert text set to bold in Jquery

Tags: jquery, text

Is there anyway to set bold the text from JQuery inside sweet alert `swal.fire`
I already tried this but it doesn't work at all

**The current result** `<strong> textsample </strong>"` it should bold the text

```
Swal.fire({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: identifier_swal +" " + "<strong>" +  $genericname + "</strong>" +" as Generic name?",
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true
 });
```

Comment: use `html` instead of `text`